# How can I link comments or answers in url using url#Id?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

Sometime I need to share answer with someone and want that directly user get focus on the answer or comment I am referring I have seen Urls containing the Id of post or comment with #, Is there a way I can directly generate that url to share with someone.

For Example:

I want to share the first answer first comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13947592/821057). How I can get referencing url.

Share link on the answers generate the different link than the way I am define above. There should be a simple way to generate this url like

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628145/form-refresh-after-submit-event/18628232?noredirect=1#comment27423764_18628232`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date next to the comment is a link to the URL that you want.

Clicking on the link will set the URL anchor to the comment, it also gets highlighted and scrolled into view. Then copy that URL from the address bar and share it. Or just open the context menu with a right-click on that link and select "Copy link location" (the name of this option probably differs between browsers).